# How to use "say" in Perl onelines without declaring 'use v5.11' or similar?

Tags: perl

In newer Perls there is "say" command that behaves like println:

```
$ perl -e 'use v5.11; say "qqq"'
qqq
```

but it's a bit cumbersome to use in oneliners, as one needs to declare version...

```
$ perl -e 'say "qqq"'
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "say "qqq""

$ perl -e 'print "qqq\n"'
qqq # but \n is easy for forget and "print" is longer...
```

Is there a way to enable `say` without adding slashes (there can already by plenty of in the line) or moving cursor left to type `use v5.11` in command line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If calling perl from the command line, you can use the `-E` flag

- `-E program`:        like `-e`, but enables all optional features

As demonstrated:

```
$ perl -E 'say "qqq"'
qqq
```

Comment: Thanks. I've looked for word "version" in `perldoc perlrun`, but `-E` wasn't nearby...

Comment: I often use `perl -dwe 0` to get an interactive Perl command line interface. But `perl -dwE 0` doesn't enable the `say` command.

Answer (score 7):

As an option to `-E`, I use `-l`, which makes `print` work like `say` (add a newline). I use this most of the time myself, and I find that it completely replaces `say`.

```
$ perl -lwe'print "foo"'
foo
```

What it really does is set `$\` to the current value of `$/`, which causes the oddity that the command line option `-0` affects `-l`, which is something to look out for. The order of the switches matter, so that

```
$ perl -l -00 -e'print "hi"'
```

works as expected, but

```
$ perl -00 -l -e'print "hi"'
```

Does not (it sets `$\` to `"\n\n"`, for paragraph mode).

This latter case is practical when using paragraph mode, for re-printing the paragraphs easily. All in all, there are many benefits to using `-l`.

Technically, `print` is longer than `say`, but my fingers already type `print` automatically, and `print` is in the actual case shorter than `print^H^H^H^H^Hsay`..  (backspace that is)

Comment: I too always use `-l` for my one-liners mostly because of the ancient `perl` (5.8.8) at work does not support the `-E` option.

Comment: Yet another reason: `awk` is very alike to `perl`, hence we `awk` programmers are used to `print(f)` and would not really be keen on having to remember yet another statement for text output if there is no actual need :)

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -E'say "foo";'                   # 5.10+ (Forward-incompatible!)
perl -Mfeature=say -e'say "foo";'     # 5.10+
perl -M5.010 -e'say "foo";'           # 5.10+
perl -e'CORE::say "foo";'             # 5.16+
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43685448/589924) for how `-E` can cause problems.

Comment: Is specifically the `say` in danger and there are proposed breaking changes about it, or rather `-E` is in general not the best idea outside throw-away oneliners?

Comment: The latter, as explained in the linked page. `-E` causes backwards incompatible changes to be enabled, so a program that works today might stop working tomorrow if it uses `-E`.