# Perl CORE::say vs -E

Tags: perl

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43683060/632407) is used the perl one-liner as:

```
perl -we '... CORE::say "x=$x"'
```

What is the advantage using the `-e` and `CORE::say` instead of the shorter: `-E` and plain `say`, e.g.:

```
perl -wE '... say "x=$x"'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[feature.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feature) was introduced to allow backwards-incompatible features to be added to Perl. `-E` enables all backward-incompatible features, which means a program that uses `-E` may break if you upgrade `perl`.

```
perl               -E'... say "foo";       ...'   # Forward-incompatible (5.10+)
perl -Mfeature=say -e'... say "foo";       ...'   # ok (5.10+)
perl -Mv5.10       -e'... say "foo";       ...'   # ok (5.10+)
perl -M5.010       -e'... say "foo";       ...'   # ok (5.10+)
perl               -e'... CORE::say "foo"; ...'   # ok (5.16+)
```

---

For example, say you wrote the following program in 2010:

```
perl -E'sub fc { my $acc=1; $acc*=$_ for 2..$_[0]; $acc } say fc(5);'
```

With the latest Perl in 2010 (5.12), the program outputs the following:

```
120
```

With the latest Perl in 2016 (5.24), the program outputs the following:

```
5
```

The difference is due to the addition of a feature to 5.16 that changes the meaning of that program when enabled. If one had avoided the use of `-E`, the program's behaviour would not have changed. Specifically, the following outputs `120` in 5.24:

```
perl -e'sub fc { my $acc=1; $acc*=$_ for 2..$_[0]; $acc } CORE::say fc(5);'
```

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Maybe you should add that `fc` is a builtin since 5.16 (it's not that often used and therefor I'm pretty sure some people don't know about it, in which case it's not obvious why both programs behave differently)

Comment: @Dada, It's not `fc`'s addition that's the problem, it's the enabling of the `fc` feature that's the problem.

Comment: That's what I meant: I only know since a few months of `fc` and I'm pretty sure some people without a lot of experience with Perl don't know about it. I think your example doesn't make much sense for someone that doesn't know that `fc` feature exists.

Comment: It is strange, in 1st version of the answer i got a feeling that I understand.  Now again, not fully. :(  While the `fc` example nice (as `fc` is introduced in 5.16), But, I can't imagine, what could be broken (in some future perl version) in the simle addition, as in the linked answer: `perl -we'my $x = 0; my $y = $x + 1; CORE::say "x=$x"'` . Looks like i need much more learning...

Comment: @kobame, You're looking at it backwards. You shouldn't spend time analysing your program to guess if it's likely to be broken by a future feature. That's a futile waste of time, because the answer is invariably yes. (e.g. `/\s/` is affected by a feature.) Instead, you should simply avoid `-E` unless you have a reason to use it. (Specifically, if you'll never use the program again.)

Comment: @Dada, Re "*I think your example doesn't make much sense for someone that doesn't know that fc feature exists.*", But that's the point. You never know what features will exist. How the program breaks is not important, only that it can.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the difference like this:

```
C:\> perl -MO=Deparse -E "say"
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'postderef_qq', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
say $_;
```

This is with `perl` 5.24.1 Now, without `-E`:

```
C:\> perl -MO=Deparse -e "CORE::say"
CORE::say $_;
-e syntax OK
```

The feature set included with `-E` will change in later versions (e.g. subroutine signatures) the wholesale inclusion of which may break existing programs. On the other hand, the latter will work with version 5.16 and later as @ikegami [listed](/a/43685448/100754) without other features clashing with programs written before their introduction.