# why $_ doesn't change between single and global replace

Tags: perl

I have these 4 statements

```
$ perl -e ' $in="axaxaxhhhh"; $in=~s/a/p/ for 1..2 ; print $in '  # 1. Ok
pxpxaxhhhh

$ perl -e ' $_="axaxaxhhhh"; $_=~s/a/p/ for 1..2 ; print $_ ' # 2. Why not working?
axaxaxhhhh

$ perl -e ' $_="axaxaxhhhh"; $_=~s/a/p/g; print $_ ' # 3.good
pxpxpxhhhh

$ perl -e ' $_="axaxaxhhhh"; $_=~s/a/p/; print $_ ' # 4.good 
pxaxaxhhhh

$
```

what is happening in my second case ?. why it is not modifying $_?

Comment: @zdim.. thank you.. just updated.. btw stuck with work and coming here after sometime..

Comment: The foreach loop aliases `$_` to the scalars returned by `1..2`. You are performing the substitution against those temporary scalars.

Comment: @stack0114106 "_stuck with work_" -- it's good to be busy with work.  I mean, I hope it's good work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a for loop, the loop variable is scoped. Thus, the command

```
$x=17; for $x (1..2) { say $x } say $x;
```

results in `$x` being restored to its original value after having left the loop:

```
1
2
17
```

The implicit variable `$_` makes no exception: you get the same result from the command

```
$_=17; say for (1..2); say;
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the "more local" `$_` is the one of the loop. Observe how

```
perl -E "\$_ = 'abc'; print(\$_) for 1 .. 2; print(\$_);"
```

prints `12abc` instead of `abcabcabc`.

From ["perlvar -- SPECIAL VARIABLES -- General Variables"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#SPECIAL-VARIABLES):

> - `$_`
>     ...
>
>   Here are the places where Perl will assume `$_` even if you don't use it:
>
>   ...
>
>   - The default iterator variable in a `foreach` loop if no other variable is supplied.

And from ["perlsyn -- Foreach Loops"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops):

> The `foreach` keyword is actually a synonym for the `for` keyword, so you can use either. If VAR is omitted, `$_` is set to each value.

Comment: I suggest to change `-E` to `-e` since no features are used here.   (This simply used the OP I guess, but that was changed as well.   See my comment under OP)

Comment: (that comment removed -- the gist of it was that there are [reasons against using `-E`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43685448/4653379))